# How do you run multiple requests or thread groups parallely "for each of the same user" in JMeter

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, jmeter

Adding multiple requests to same thread group also seem to run sequentially.

I know you can start thread groups in parallel but I want all thread groups to run or start in parallel for the SAME user.

And then you have the synchronizing timer that starts multiple users at the exact time
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer
But this does not scale all users concurrently based on throughput and **is very hacky** i.e., you have to parameterize your users and the group by in such a way to match expected throughput and number of requests per user

Right now, the work around is to create an HTML page to trigger download embedded resources in parallel for same user in one thread group but that is ugly and only works for GET requests. Also this is very buggy and runs very slow besides occupying full CPU and the throughput is 1/10th of a separate parallel test showing that this does not work correctly.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448625/jmeter-fire-multiple-concurrent-http-requests-for-a-single-user

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same approach as for AJAX testing with JMeter which assumes running multiple requests of different types at the same moment of time. It assumes some scripting so you will have to write a bit of Groovy or Java code in [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or even create your own sampler, fortunately JMeter module plugin-oriented architecture is very extension-friendly as it evidenced by [JMeter Plugins project](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) (take a look by the way, perhaps your use case is already implemented)

See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for explanation of the approach and few code snippets demonstrating how to run parallel asynchronous requests

Comment: How different is this from writing my own concurrent pool of executors with each executor running a few threads that are warmed up and reused to run few threads in parallel in an executor?